# I couldn't understand a sentence while watching The Big Bang Theory

Tags: meaning

Recently I've been watching The Big Bang Theory with scripts. In one of the videos, they said:

> "I’ve got a girl who punishes her father by sleeping around and an alcoholic who’s two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat."

I could understand the meaning, but couldn't understand the structure of this sentence. Is there anybody who can help me with figuring it out??

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I will show you the full sentence:  I've got a hot former fat girl with no self-esteem, I got a girl who punishes her father by sleeping around, and an alcoholic who's two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat. I wonder if  this sentence is grammatically correct. I've already understood the meaning, but all the answers just comment about meaning, not syntax.

Comment: @JoeHwang Show us the full sentence in the question, please :-). Do not clarify or amend your own questions in comments.

Comment: hi new user Joe!   the excellent ELL site exists to answer questions such as this.  Enjoy!

Comment: I think you might be confused by the "I've got...." syntax which is very American, it's a common, colloquial way that people offer their goods or services. Like a salesmen says "I've got a car with x cupholders and a truck that's ready to tour Alaska!" Obviously Penny doesn't own the two girls but by saying "I've got" suggests she is *offering* them to Howard.

Answer (score 43):

It helps to see more context:

> Penny: [on phone] How about this: you keep him there a little longer, and when you get to the party, I'll point out which of my friends are easy.
>
> Howard: [long pause] Don't toy with me, woman.
>
> Penny: I've got a hot former fat girl with no self-esteem, I got a girl who punishes her father by sleeping around, and an alcoholic who's two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat.

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory_(season_1)#ep16))

Penny says she has friends who are "easy", meaning they are sexually active and not discriminating about who they sleep with.

Howard questions whether this is true.

Then Penny gives descriptions of three of her friends to prove her point.

"Sleeping around" means having many sexual partners.

"Two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat" isn't an established idiom, just something the script-writers thought was a clever way to describe someone who's willing to have sex because of being very drunk (I'm not sure I agree with them).

> I could understand the meaning, but couldn't understand the structure of this sentence.

"I got" is a shortened form of "I have" or "I have got". The structure is the same as "I have a dog and a cat" except the two things she has are described with long phrases rather than simple nouns.

**Edit**

In comments, there have been several possible meanings suggested for the phrase "wear her like a hat":

1. It refers to sex.
2. It refers to vaginal sex because "hat" is slang for a condom.
3. It refers to cunnilingus (aka "face-sitting").
4. It just means she'd allow him to do whatever he wants.

I think this wide variety of interpretations itself suggests the phrase is not a widely established idiom (It could be established in some communities, but not across the English-speaking world, and it might have different meanings in different communities)

It is a metaphor, and it does have a sexual meaning, but it's up to each person to determine for themselves what the exact meaning is.

Comment: When you wear a hat, your head is inside the hat. I'll let you extrapolate the rest on your own.

Comment: @SomethingDark, I agree that it is meant to refer to sex. I don't agree that this is a well-known slang term for a condom in American English.

Comment: I agree that this has nothing to do with condoms; I had something slightly more sexually graphic in mind.

Comment: @SomethingDark are you referring to Bent's comment on the other answer?

Comment: Yep, that's where I was going with that.

Comment: I do not think this is referring to any particular act. "letting you wear her like a hat" simply means, that she will not object to anything.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Not everything needs to be a well-established slang term or idiom, as long as the speaker uses an expression that makes sense to the listener. Secondly, pretty much all euphemisms (which "wearing you like a hat" is) start out as neologisms, specifically because a _new_ phrasing is not yet regulated by etiquette/censorship and you can therefore get away with it. This has spawned a whole subset of comedy where the euphemism is unknown yet clearly reveals its true meaning. "Wear your like a hat" is an example of such a _clear yet indirect_ euphemism.

Comment: "Wear her like a hat" is a very established idiom with a very clear meaning [oral sex, sat on face] - but oddly doesn't seem to have made it to the urban dictionaries, even though I've known it for 30 or 40 years. Maybe it's UK-slang only.

Comment: @Tetsujin, if you can document that, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Flater, Of course we don't always speak in idiomatic expressions. But explaining the literal meaning of words like "wear" and "hat" is off topic here.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with [The Photon's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464965/i-couldnt-understand-a-sentence-while-watching-the-big-bang-theory/464968#464968) for the most part, but could provide an additional perspective.

> Two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat

to me implies that after two shots of Tequila, she would let Howard "wear" her on his other head (penis), like a condom. This seems to fit with Howard's goal of getting laid.

Comment: Too much information. :-)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Only mentioned it because The Photon thought it was a way to describe someone who's very drunk, which they didn't agree with. Wasn't sure if it should be in a comment or separate answer though. Looking at the OP more closely though, they seem to already understand the meaning, so perhaps a comment would be better?

Comment: I would have made it a comment on Photon's answer.  But hey, it got you an upvote. I think that your analysis is right.  I also might have been more oblique, such as, "BTW, 'hat' is slang for a condom." But that is just me.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, where is "hat" established slang for a condom? I'll accept it's likely meant to be meant as a euphemism for a condom, but I don't think it's used frequently enough to be understood that way without context.

Comment: "wear her like a hat" - I think it is implying that she will put her nether regions on his head.

Comment: @ThePhoton See definition number 4.   https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hat

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56, I guess that answers my question, "Where..." since it says that usage is "(British)". I still don't think many people in the American audience would connect "hat" with "condom" without the very suggestive context we have here.

Comment: @Bent Where I grew up, we had other words for that.

Comment: I think we saw the "hat" girl in the episode. It ends with Penny and Leonard watching a video of the party, in which Raj has a drunken girl riding his shoulders. The phrase "wearing her like a hat" could be an exaggeration of this activity.

Comment: It doesn't have any specific meaning - i'd interpret it as "she will not object to anything" - without any genitalia related particularities... Get yer heads out of the gutters

Comment: "implies that after two shots of tequila" – There's more to it. It means she is already so drunk that after _just_ two **more** shots of tequila she will be drunk enough to do anything.

Comment: I always assumed it was oral sex :P the "other head" side of things wasn't my first thought at all.

Comment: Yes, it's oral sex... wear like a hat == sit on your face. [I can't believe I just wrote that in public;)

Comment: @NigelTouch I understood it to mean that two shots of tequila are by themselves sufficient to render her intoxicated.

Answer (score 5):

**I** - subject
**have got** - verb
**a girl** - first direct object
**who punishes her father by sleeping around** - relative clause modifying first direct object
**and** - conjunction joining first and second direct objects
**an alcoholic** - second direct object
**who’s two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat.** - relative clause modifying second direct object

Does that help you understand the structure?

Comment: This seems to be the only answer responsive to the request to explain the structure of the sentence.  The "punishes" phrase and the "tequila shots" phrase are [relative clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause#Relative_clauses), and you've omitted "who" from the beginning of the first of those.

Comment: @phoog Edited to reflect

Comment: I already upvoted, so I can't upvote any more :-(

Comment: @Kevin This is what I wanted. But let me ask you one more thing.  Could you explain "who's two tequila shots away from letting you wear her like a hat." with more details?

Answer (score 4):

Let me translate ...

Context: Penny is describing two of her girlfriends (or acquaintences) who are very sexually available.

*"I’ve got a ..."*: this means, "I know a" or "I can provide you with a". It is the kind of language you would use if you were operating an agency providing staff. (For example, "I have got someone working for me who can come and fix your television"). Otherwise, you would not refer to people like that as it would be considered rude.

*" hot "*: sexy.

*" former fat girl"*: a girl (or woman) who was formerly (previously) overweight, but now isn't.

*"with no self-esteem"*: self-esteem is how you think of yourself; how attractive, talented or important you think you are (usually relative to others). So "no self-esteem" means that you think you are worthless. It might be implied that this person still thinks she is unattractive because of her previous weight problems, even though she now is "hot".

*" who punishes her father "*: the girl has a bad relationship with her father and likes to hurt him by doing things that he does not want her to do.

*"by sleeping around"*: the thing her father doesn't want is her having sex with a lot of people in very short term relationships.

*" and an alcoholic"*: someone addicted to alcohol.

*" who’s two tequila shots away "*: who only needs to drink two shots (small glasses) of tequila until she is drunk enough to do something.

*" from letting you wear her like a hat."*: this requires some imagination. It is probably a vulgar way of saying "letting you have sex with her", although I don't think it is an widely used expression. But imagine the act of a man putting a hat on his head, and then think of his head as some other part of his body. It might also be referring to the fact that a hat is something you put on and take off daily without much thought or trouble.

If you get as far as understanding all of this, you are doing quite well with your English studies. However, the language is quite vulgar (offensive in the wrong situations) and you should be very careful how you use it.